# Python File "setup.py" in run raise RuntimeError("chmod error") RuntimeError: chmod error

Tags: python, django, jython

I am trying to install a few modules for Jython/Python Django app I have on Windows 7. When I try to install them after downloading them (navigate to the directory, from a command prompt type jython setup.py install) I get the following error (the one below is for Pycrypto-2.6:

```
    running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
running build_configure
'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 456, in <module>
    core.setup(**kw)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 513, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 112, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 251, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\jython2.5.3\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 273, in run
    raise RuntimeError("chmod error")
   RuntimeError: chmod error
```

I went into the setup.py file and commented out the chmod line. I re-ran it and got an error on "sh configure". I just stopped there as I don't know how to invoke the configure command in this module.

Obviously this has to do with me trying to install this on windows and not Linux. But with Jython I cannot install this with easy_install. And pip won't work with Jython. So I don't know how to install this module myself.

Thanks

Comment: Another user on a forum helped me with jython pip. I issued `jython -m pip search pycrypto` and it showed the desired module in a list. I then issued `jython -m pip install pycrypto` but it fails to install it. I see the code downloaded to a directory. But the egg is empty. So I again try to install it through the command line with the chmod error failing it. I don't know what to do here.

Comment: I don't know why there is a problem . . . would like to . . . but here is how I just got around this to install the modules. Again, when using Python and pip things on Windows were effortless.I is just Jython and pip and Windows that I encountered this.

Comment: My jython is install in C:\jython2.5.3\
My pip was manually downloaded and installed in C:|jython2.5.3\bin

So I would attempt the install with pip
     jython -m pip install xxxx

if it said that there wasn't such a module I would search for it
     jython -m pip search <module name>

if that didn't turn antyhing up after the search I went to http://pypi.python.org/simple and looked for it and installed it with URL
     jython -m pip install http://pypi.python.org/simple/<xxxx>/<xxx.gz>

Comment: the URL has to be the file page so right click on link that pops up the file download window to copy the URL and use in the command if it came back from install and said that it downloaded it but no files/directories were found . . . etc . . . I would cd to the directory  that it displayed it downloaded the files to and just manually install it with the following 
    jython -m setup.py install

Comment: This usually worked. Of course I have 3 modules that still won't import into jython after all of this (chmod error, not supported in Jython, etc) But that is a different matter